# ng-click not working with .load(html)

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am loading html with `<script>$(".header").load("headerDrawNav.html");</script>` and I have a ng-click on one of the buttons and it calls a function in *test.js* file but nothing happens when the button is clicked.

I get the warning.

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is
>   deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's
>   experience

**headerDrawNav.html**

```
<div class="headerButtons">
    <button id="save" type="button" class="btn" ng-click="saveState()">Save</button>
</div>
```

test.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css">
    <script src="/controllers/test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as $ctrl">

        <div class="header">
        </div>
        <script>$(".header").load("headerDrawNav.html");</script>
        </div>

      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','$http','$interval'];
  function MainCtrl($scope, $http, $interval) {
     $scope.saveState = function(){
        console.log("Saving")
   }
}
```

Comment: First off, you have an extra </div> tag. Secondly, you can have the controller use a template, in this case your headerDrawNav.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angularjs has the directive `ng-include` can do the loading for you. Just use it and the `button` will working. example:

```
<div ng-include="'headerDrawNav.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Oh worked perfectly did not realize that was a thing. Thank you!